# How to copy .git files from jenkins workspace to a remote server

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to copy files from Jenkins workspace to a remote server, but all the files were copied except .git and its related files are not copied.

I used **Publish Over ssh** plugin to copy file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post build action, do this-> Check the **No default excludes** checkbox which is present under the **Advanced** section of **Send build artifacts over SSH** and it will upload your .git files. Please see the screenshot attached.[image]